# How to create a Flex Display component in Flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, components, flash-cs3

I have used Flash to make skins, which I import and apply to Flex components.

But how can I create a component in Flash, with properties and methods. And make it able to be added to the displayList in a Flex app?

I installed the Flex component kit for flash. Created my component in flash (it extends MovieClip). Did `Command->Convert to flex Component`, did `File->Published`, which gave me a .swc, dropped the .sec file into my Flex project. Now when I create a new var the class "FlashFlexComponentTest" pops up in the new class hint box, so flex sees it. But afterwards I get the error:

> Type was not found or was not a
> compile-time constant: FlashFlexComponentTest

I feel like I must be missing a step?

Thanks!

## UPDATE

I added the .swc via project build path -> add SWC.
I no longer have a compile-time error but I am getting a runtime error:

> Type Coercion failed: cannot convert FlashFlexClassTest@9089129 to mx.core.IUIComponent

Answer (score 1):

The base class for all flex components, UIComponent, allows you to add Sprites that don't implement the IUIComponent interface.

An example :

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical"
    creationComplete="init();">

  <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        private function init():void 
        {
            var component:FlashFlexClassTest = new FlashFlexClassTest();
            container.addChild(component);
        }

     ]]>
  </mx:Script>
  <mx:UIComponent id="container" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good video tutorial on this at Linda.com by David something.  I did a lot of this a year or so ago, and that was the best resource I found.  Doesn't cover absolutely every possible angle, but does a great job of covering what you *need* to know.

I'm guessing there's just some small linkage detail that you're missing.  The tutorial should get you straight, if that's the case.  It was worth the $20, or whatever, for a monthly subscription for me.

Sorry, that's the best I can do... haven't built Flex components in Flash since last year.

Comment: Well I am wondering if maybe I should have used Command->Convert to flex Container instead of component. Thanks ill look for the linda video.

Answer (score 0):

basically there are step what need to do:

1. open Flash
2. drag a component you need to stage
3. right click on it in Library > Export to SWC
4. put this SWC in your Flash Builder libs folder

There is explanation by Jesse Warden http://jessewarden.com/2011/06/integrating-flash-components-with-flex-revisited.html

Cheers!